# Swift Playground - Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(size:)' for class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground, initializer

I have a class Branch and I have implemented my custom initializer for it. I got an error stating that I have not implemented the `init?(coder aDecoder)` initializer, which I implemented after that. I am still getting an error saying

```
Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(size:)' for class 'wwdcGame_Sources.Branch'
```

I tried implementing the initializer but I am just getting more and more errors. And I could not find any other answer to this.

Any help is much appreciated. I have been sitting on this issue for a long time. Thanks in advance.

**Branch.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import CoreGraphics

public class Branch : SKScene {

    var begin = CGPoint()
    var end = CGPoint()
    var finished: Bool = false

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public required init(_ begin: CGPoint,_ end: CGPoint,_ finished: Bool){
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end
        self.finished = finished
        super.init()
    }

    public func show() {
        var points = [CGPoint(x: begin.x, y: begin.y),
                      CGPoint(x: end.x, y: end.y)]
        let line = SKShapeNode(points: &points,
                                          count: points.count)
        line.lineWidth = 5
        addChild(line)
    }

    public func branchRight() -> Branch {

        let angle : Float = (30 * Float(Double.pi) / 180)
        let point = CGPoint(x: end.x - begin.y , y : end.y - begin.y)
        let dir_x = Float(point.x)
        let dir_y = Float(point.y)

        var rotatedPoint : CGPoint = point
        rotatedPoint.x = CGFloat(dir_x * cosf(angle) - dir_y * sinf(angle)) * 0.67
        rotatedPoint.y = CGFloat(dir_y * cosf(angle) + dir_x * sinf(angle)) * 0.67

        let newEnd = CGPoint(x : end.x + rotatedPoint.x, y: end.y + rotatedPoint.y)
        return(Branch(end,newEnd,false))
    }

    public func branchLeft() -> Branch{

        let angle : Float = -(30 * Float(Double.pi) / 180)
        let point = CGPoint(x: end.x - begin.y , y : end.y - begin.y)
        let dir_x = Float(point.x)
        let dir_y = Float(point.y)

        var rotatedPoint : CGPoint = point
        rotatedPoint.x = CGFloat(dir_x * cosf(angle) - dir_y * sinf(angle)) * 0.67
        rotatedPoint.y = CGFloat(dir_y * cosf(angle) + dir_x * sinf(angle)) * 0.67

        let newEnd = CGPoint(x : end.x + rotatedPoint.x, y: end.y + rotatedPoint.y)
        return(Branch(end,newEnd,false))

    }

}
```

I am using this class in turn in another scene. Including this class just in case.

**FractalTreesScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

public class FractalTreesScene: SKScene {

    var tree = [Branch]()
    var leaves = [CGPoint]()

    var count = 0;
    let tree_width = 400
    let tree_height = 0

    override public func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.scene!.backgroundColor = SKColor.black

        let a = CGPoint(x: tree_width,y: tree_height)
        let b = CGPoint(x: tree_width,y: tree_height + 100)
        let root = Branch(a,b,false)
        tree[0] = root

        for i in stride(from: tree.count, to: 0, by: -1) {
            if (tree[i].finished == false) {
                tree.append(tree[i].branchRight());
                tree.append(tree[i].branchLeft());
            }
            tree[i].finished = true;
            count += 1;

            if (count == 6) {
                for i in 0..<tree.count {
                    if (!tree[i].finished) {
                        let leaf = tree[i].end
                        leaves.append(leaf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for i in 0..<tree.count {
            tree[i].show()
        }

        for i in 0..<leaves.count {
            let leaf = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 3.0)
            leaf.position = leaves[i]
            leaf.fillColor = .red
            addChild(leaf)
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: This is the contents.swift file where I instantiate the classes

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800,height:800))

if let scene = FractalTreesScene(fileNamed: "FractalTreesScene") {
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    view.presentScene(scene)
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: Try to reduce your code example to the minimum needed.

Answer (score 2):

Override `init(size:)`:

```
public override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
}
```

As you have a custom initializer, your `Branch` class does not inherit the `init(size:)`.

Comment: That error went away, and a new one popped up `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
`

Comment: That's a playground issue. Once I solved this with the help of this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63228

Comment: I tried using those solutions, and i tried restarting xcode but its still throwing that error

Comment: Can you provide the code where you instantiate and use those classes?

Comment: Added the file, and branch.swift I am using in the FractalTreesScene.swift file

Comment: Unfortunately I could not reproduce your error, but I would suggest you to use an actual application instead of using playgrounds. This kind of problem is really common with playgrounds.

Comment: This was for the wwdc application which requires the use of playgrounds. Thanks for help. Xcode has being acting wierd the entire afternoon, it isn't opening the simple views now